# Identificar Fragment actual

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, onbackpressed

Inicio con activity Login y al loggear se va a Main, dentro de main esta un navigation drawer con fragments.

Quiero que el onBackPressed, funcione en los fragment, pero al momento de estar en el HomeFragment no haga nada.

Sin embargo no logro identificar en que fragment se encuentra actualmente, o hay otro proceso?

Answer (score 1):

Si esta usando nombre para cada fragment, lo recomendable seria que en el main al presionar hacia atras verifique que titulo tiene el fragment actual.
El cual se usa en el mismo mainActiviy de la siguiente manera:

```
 if(!getSupportActionBar().getTitle().equals("Inicio")){//Aqui se esta diciendo que si el fragment actual es diferente a el de home o Inicio. inicio
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cnl_contenedor, new HomeFragment()).commit();//Entonces llevarlo al fragment de Inico




        }else{

//Sino, no hacer nada

        }
```

Para ponerle nombre a cada fragment, cuando lo llame se escribe el siguiente codigo

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Nombre del fragment");
```

Cualquier duda preguntar.